# I can be caught but not liked a lot

Tags: word

I can

Go with your heart but not with your brain

Mess with your head but not with your hair

Flow with your blood and hang with your shoulder

Stay with your feet but not with your ankle

Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

> **COLD** - and each of the lines in this riddle describe words that can (or cannot) be connected *with* 'cold' to make common phrases.

*I can: Go with your heart but not with your brain*

> You can describe someone as '**cold-hearted**' (but not 'cold-brained'...).

*I can: Mess with your head but not with your hair*

> You can have a '**head cold**' (but not a 'hair cold'...).

*I can: Flow with your blood and hang with your shoulder*

> Some animals are '**cold-blooded**', and you can give someone the '**cold shoulder**'.

*I can: Stay with your feet but not with your ankle*

> You can get '**cold feet**' and chicken out of something (but you can't get 'cold ankles'...).

And as for the title:

> You can *catch* a cold, but you won't enjoy it!